# Add Dynamic text field using Javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic

Field Item                                                Field Qty
--------                                                           -----
  --------                                                            ------
--------                                                           -----
  --------                                                            ------
ADD MORE

Item field and quantity are manually entered by user and if they need more items to be entered they will click on add more button 
I have a form of 5 rows with two column each as above .

I want to add more text field dynamically, onclick add more button and I need to get the values through POST using PHP .

I have seen similar post but they either add only one input field at a time or a bunch of fields.

I want both  fields item and qty to be added on a single click .

```
<form id="quick_post" method="post"> 
<table id="input_fields">
 <tr> 
   <td><input class="orderinput" type="text" name="product[]">        
   </td> 
     <td><input class="orderquan" type="text" name="quantity[]" size="1" maxlength="3">  
  </td>
</tr> 
   <tr>
       <td>
           //In here i want to add more Input Text product fields 
        </td>
       <td>
           //In here i want to add more Input Text Quantity fields 
        </td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><input class="more" type="submit" value="Addmore" name="addmore"></td>  
    </tr>
 </table> </form>
```

Comment: will all inputs be input-text?

Comment: If you're a beginner then you might want to have a look at the [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) JavaScript library. It has solutions to all problems regarding creating an interactive User-Interfaces. It also has plenty of tutorials online.

Learning a new library is always a plus.

Comment: You should take those other examples you found, and modify them to fit your needs. In other words, try something for yourself first. ...and don't use a library right away like others may suggest. Learn the basics first.

Comment: In the question there is a little information because is better that your adding the code.

Comment: Yes Input text. <td><input class="orderinput" type="text" name="product[]"></td> <td><input class="orderquan" type="text" name="quantity[]" size="1" maxlength="3"></td>   . I want to achieve something similar to the question . some basic ideas or suggestions can be useful .

Comment: look this fiddle modify it http://jsfiddle.net/m9NFd/11/

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***`Working jsFiddle Demo`***](http://jsfiddle.net/gtWu3/)

- `[!]` This solution need [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/).

Put the `Add More` button outside the `form`:

```
<form id="quick_post" method="post"> 
    <table id="input_fields">
        <tr> 
            <td><input class="orderinput" type="text" name="product[]" /></td> 
            <td><input class="orderquan" type="text" name="quantity[]" size="1" maxlength="3" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<input class="more" type="button" value="Addmore" name="addmore" />
```

And add a `click` handler to your button:

```
$(function () {
    $('input.more').on('click', function () {
        var $table = $('#input_fields');
        var $tr = $table.find('tr').eq(0).clone();
        $tr.appendTo($table).find('input').val('');
    });
});
```

Note that this need [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com/). Don't forget to check [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gtWu3/).

**[BONUS] How to include jQuery in your project:**

Put `jQuery` file and the above function inside the `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input.more').on('click', function () {
            var $table = $('#input_fields');
            var $tr = $table.find('tr').eq(0).clone();
            $tr.appendTo($table).find('input').val('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have no knowledge about Jquery how to call this function in the page where do i paste the Jquery script?

Comment: That is working in jsfiddle demo ,   how do i get the value form the text field  using post should i use foreach () ? or any other method . i prefer it to be foreach .

Comment: @RajaMOhammed I've updated my answer: how to include jQuery in your project. How to fetch the data in PHP, is another question. I suggest you leave this question for `Add More` button, and ask another question: `How to retrieve text fields as an array in PHP`.

Comment: @RajaMOhammed For quick answer yes. You can get data with POST. Try this in your PHP code (after submitting the form): `<?php print_r($_POST['product']); ?>`.